# Move screen up when keyboard appears in iPhone X

Tags: ios, swift, uikeyboard

I use code below to move screen up and down when keyboard show and hide

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()            
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector:#selector(ViewController.keyboardWillShow), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ViewController.keyboardWillHide), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)    
}

@objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {        
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
        if self.view.frame.origin.y == 0{
            self.view.frame.origin.y -= keyboardSize.height
        }
    }        
}

@objc func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
        if self.view.frame.origin.y != 0{
            self.view.frame.origin.y += keyboardSize.height
        }
    }
}
```

It works in all devices except iPhone x (I think the problem is iPhone X bottom wasted space)

Problem is that keyboard size change before shown and after that and cause the view go down and down and down...

Can anyone help?

Comment: well i'm having same issue than i endup using `iqKeyboardmanager` and set distance between inputfield and keyboard 40.

Comment: wow its you again @PratikPrajapati :)
can I see your code please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it is,
Use `IQKeyboardManagerSwift`

AppDelegate.swift settings

```
IQKeyboardManager.shared.enable = true
IQKeyboardManager.shared.enableAutoToolbar = false
```

In My ViewController

```
func textViewShouldBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView) -> Bool {
    print(#function)
    if DeviceType.checkiPhoneX() {
        IQKeyboardManager.shared.keyboardDistanceFromTextField = 40.0
    }        
    return true
}

 func textViewDidEndEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
    if DeviceType.checkiPhoneX() {
        IQKeyboardManager.shared.keyboardDistanceFromTextField = 0.0
    }
}
```

This is how i manage Keyboard for X.

Hope this may help you.

Comment: It is possible to handle keyboard easily without external libraries.

Comment: yes absolutely, i'm just showing my tried code as he request

Answer (score 1):

You should also consider safe area insets

```
let endFrame = (userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue ?? CGRect.zero
let bottomSpace = keyboardValues.endFrame.maxY - keyboardValues.endFrame.minY - self.view.safeAreaInsets.bottom
```

And you should not be additive. These notifications may be posted multiple times. Use absolute values.

Answer (score -1):

Use **UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey** instead of UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey.