# Keyboard overlaps textfiled inside lisview Item in IOS

Tags: ios, nativescript

In the nativescript app, I am using listview that contains input text-field in each row.

As I am using `<activity android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">` in my android manifest, it works fine in android but in ios for smaller devices keyboard overlaps the textfield.

Although I am using [nativescript-iqkeyboardmanager](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-iqkeyboardmanager) as well.

Is it because of **un**available space for listview ? I am suspecting that `IQKeyboardManager` is unable to detect the height of individual item in listview and scrolls the whole listview up.
Here is the [screenshot](https://ibb.co/mFdPye).

Comment: check this [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52232926/move-screen-up-when-keyboard-appears-in-iphone-x/52233181?noredirect=1#comment91415469_52233181), use `keyboardDistanceFromTextField`

Comment: let me check if that property is available for nativescript plugin.

Comment: It is available for NativeScript, you don't have limitations in accessing native apis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const iqKeyboard = IQKeyboardManager.sharedManager();
iqKeyboard.overrideKeyboardAppearance = true;
iqKeyboard.keyboardAppearance = UIKeyboardAppearance.Dark;
iqKeyboard.keyboardDistanceFromTextField = 40.0
```

Need to add references for NativeScript /Typescript as [example](https://github.com/tjvantoll/nativescript-IQKeyboardManager/blob/master/demo/references.d.ts)